# docker-compose yml file container restart order on reboots

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reboot

I have a docker compose yml file with a few containers defined:

1. database
2. web-service

I have 'depends_on' defined in 'web-service' to start after 'database'.  Both containers are defined with 'restart always'.

I've been googling and cannot find clear info on container startup order on system reboots.  Does the docker daemon read the docker-compose yml file and start the database and then web-service?  Or how does it work?

Comment: By default, Docker daemon doesn't start any containers at system boot, let alone scan your disks for compose file definitions. That stanza is used for when the container itself crashes

Comment: I'm still new to docker.  Could you clarify what starts my containers after a system reboot then?  The containers do come back up... but I would like to know is order respected due to the depends_on or do they all start back up at the same time.  @OneCricketeer

Comment: Probably systemd starts the Docker daemon at boot. And if the containers were previously running, that's when `restart: always` will bring them back up (in the order they need to be)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the containers on system startup you have to setup a some kind of "scheduled" job using e.g. Linux's CRON daemon.

Docker daemon itself is not responsible for waking-up containers, `restart` entry in compose file refers to e.g. restarting on crash of app in the container, after ending a job (which terminates terminal) and so on.

Please find the restarts explanation of docker docs https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details

Answer (score 0):

containers are started according to depends_on contraints.

on reboot too.

but you should not rely on it too much.

you can just let your web service crash when he has no acces to the db. docker will restart it automatically and it will retry. (it's cheap)

if you want to deal with it more safely/precisely, you can also wait for the port to be accessible using a script like this one.

https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

docker explains it in his documentation : https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

that way you garanty way more than depends_on. because depends only ganranty order, not that to service is ready or even working.

Comment: Thanks Raphael.  This is more for academic purposes.  Where did you find that containers are started on the depends_on constraints after a system reboot?

I've read the startup-order and understand depends_on and the restart: behaviors.  However, I can't find any documentation on what happens when the host reboots.  My containers come back up but I would like to know if the order was respected.

Comment: it came from observation. I may be wrong since i dont exactly rely on boot order as i let conainers restart as much as recessary. i would be glad if you could test it by running some containers, each logging a timestamp in a file. we will see what happens by reading the timestamps.

Comment: Or, to clarify... My confusion is around the relationship between dockerd and docker compose.  When I use docker-compose up, the yml file is read and my containers are created and started by my depends_on constraints (with restart always defined).  What I'm confused about is... when the system reboots and dockerd starts... My containers are in a running state.  Does dockerd know about my depends_on constraints or is it more basic... in that any container defined with restart-always is just started in any order at that time.

Comment: if you do "docker inspect web-service" do you see something related to depends_on ?

Comment: I've tried rebooting my system and checking the log files.  It seems like order was respected.  In the end, I won't rely on the depends_on flag, but I really want to understand that behavior.

Comment: if yes, then dockerd is aware

Comment: I just did an inspect and grepped for depends... nothing came up.

Comment: then docker itself doesnt care about depends on, its an adition of compose. so its pure luck that containers are started in order upon reboot.